# mysql sql distinct with join two table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

I have two mysql table , table `event` and table `eventvenue`.

I want to get other event from a venue.

--------------table `event`:---------------

```
id_e
id_event
title
content
```

-------------- table `eventvenue`:--------------

```
id_ev
id_event_ev
id_location_ev
```

I use join to get other event from a venue:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventvenue 
JOIN event ON eventvenue.id_event_ev = event.id_event 
WHERE eventvenue.id_location_ev=1
```

The result is:

```
id_ev  id_event_ev  id_location_ev  id_e  id_event  title   content  
-----  -----------  --------------  ----  --------  ------  ------------
1      2            1               2     2         eventA  aaaaaaaaaaaa
2      2            1               2     2         eventA  aaaaaaaaaaaa
1      4            1               4     4         eventB  bbbbbbbbb
1      9            1               9     9         eventC  cccccccc
3      5            1               5     5         event5  555555
```

The output contains two rows with the same `id_event_ev`/`id_event` value of `2`.

How can I show only **distinct** event IDs per location? Like this:

```
id_ev  id_event_ev  id_location_ev  id_e  id_event  title   content  
-----  -----------  --------------  ----  --------  ------  ------------
1      2            1               2     2         eventA  aaaaaaaaaaaa
1      4            1               4     4         eventB  bbbbbbbbb
1      9            1               9     9         eventC  cccccccc
3      5            1               5     5         event5  555555
```

Note: `id_ev` is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventvenue 
JOIN event ON eventvenue.id_event_ev = event.id_event 
WHERE eventvenue.id_location_ev=1
GROUP BY event.id_event, eventvenue.id_event_ev
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you simply want to either ignore `id_ev`, or get the lowest value of it.

This makes you need

```
SELECT DISTINCT

-- maybe drop next line
MIN(id_ev) AS id_ev, 
-- maybe drop next line

id_event_ev, id_location_ev, id_e, id_event, title, content 

FROM eventvenue 
INNER JOIN event ON eventvenue.id_event_ev = event.id_event 
WHERE eventvenue.id_location_ev=1

-- Drop next line if you dropped line above
GROUP BY eventvenue.id_ev
```

Comment: i try this code, it's work too :D
nice idea "get lowest value" :D